# A specific UIControl based around UISlider for iPhone

Tags: iphone, custom-controls, uislider

I need to show a specific bit of data to the screen and it is most easily represented as an adaptation of something like a UISlider.

It will represent a range of related (numerical) answers between 0.0 and 10.0.  The data I wish to show is the minimum, maximum and mean.  However, I need to do this without revealing the numbers.

It is currently done (on a web browser) with a control that looks like this...

[---------|=========@=====|---]

Where the shaded area shows the min-max range and the @ represents the slider thumb and is set to the mean.

Before I started trying to wrap my head around programming this I was wondering if you might be able to provide any pointers as to where I can start with this?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Thanks

Oliver

Comment: do you need to handle touch events? will the user be able to move the min/max points or mean. If not, you can draw the view with CG functions. (addLineToPoint:)

Comment: No, no input required.  It will purely be used for display purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to set this up based on the standard slider (couldn't think of a clean way to do this anyway) - and i wouldn't make it looking too similar, too. Apple is very keen on "defending" the way their UI concept is perceived by users. So i suppose they maybe wouldn't approve an app with a slider that has been "hijacked" to be only a meter, not a control - or something that looks like it, for that matter.

Maybe you'll find something in the wwww where you could base your work on, but if I were you, I'd start this element from scratch, maybe using artwork and ressources from the webbased version. This would be the most straightforward way and will give you exactly what you need..

Comment: Thanks,

I thought I might have to do something like that.

I'm fairly sure I can put together some repeating block images and stick them together in my own UIView subclass.

That way I can pass in the required numbers and let it sort itself out.

Comment: Yep... I did something similar for a custom timeline or trackview where the user may place and move animation keys. It's not too hard. Instead of repeating images for the tracks I used a very narrow image (2px wide) which would be stretched to the appropriate length, plus "cap" images for both ends.
Make sure you design your new element to be independent from the rest of your application, so you can reuse it.
Also keep the iPhone 4's retina display in mind and prepare high and low resolution versions of the resource images.
Good luck! :)